# Writing generic implementation of sum on an iterator in Rust

Tags: rust, reference, sum, iterator

I have been learning Rust, coming from a Swift, C and C++ background. I feel like I have a basic understanding of ownership, borrowing and traits. To exercise a bit, I decided to implement a `sum` function on a generic slice `[T]` where `T` has a default value and can be added to itself.

This is how far I got:

```
trait Summable {
    type Result;
    fn sum(&self) -> Self::Result;
}

impl<T> Summable for [T]
where
    T: Add<Output = T> + Default,
{
    type Result = T;

    fn sum(&self) -> T {
        let x = T::default();
        self.iter().fold(x, |a, b| a + b)
    }
}
```

Compiler complains with `expected type parameter T, found &T` for `a + b`.

I understand why the error happens, but not exactly how to fix it. Yes, the type of `x` is `T`. It cannot be `&T` because, if nothing else, if the slice is empty, that's the value that is returned and I cannot return a reference to something created inside the function. Plus, the default function returns a new value that the code inside the function owns. Makes sense. And yes, `b` should be a shared reference to the values in the slice since I don't want to consume them (not `T`) and I don't want to mutate them (not `&mut T`).

But that means I need to add `T` to `&T`, and return a `T` because I am returning a new value (the sum) which will be owned by the caller. How?

PS: Yes, I know this function exists already. This is a learning exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`std::ops::Add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html) trait has an optional `Rhs` type parameter that defaults to `Self`:

```rust
pub trait Add<Rhs = Self> {
    type Output;
    fn add(self, rhs: Rhs) -> Self::Output;
}
```

Because you've omitted the `Rhs` type parameter from the `T: Add<Output = T>` bound, it defaults to `T`: hence to your `a` you can add a `T`, but not an `&T`.

Either specify that [`T: for<'a> Add<&'a T, Output = T>`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b6b28e26be9a9af633d15264546a080a); or else somehow obtain an owned `T` from `b`, e.g. via [`T: Copy`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ab3501d06a197bfc67022e4ee306b443) or [`T: Clone`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8095d212d9749dbad92389a69f70272e).

Comment: Thanks. What would you suggest? On the one hand, first option requires that types implement that exact formulation of Add. Is this common? On the other hand, Copy/Clone requires copying for every element, potentially slower than passing a reference.

Comment: To me it seems like the first case makes the most sense assuming it is normal that types would normally implement that version of Add.

Comment: Indeed, those are the tradeoffs to consider :). Primitives do indeed `impl Add<&Self>` (albeit by copying anyway) but there's no guarantee that will be the case in general.

Comment: But in any case these two options make sense. If I was to write my own free-standing `add(x,y)` function for my own type, even in Swift/C etc, I would have to choose whether the types are passed by value or by reference into the function. Then I guess a truly generic `Summable` would have code for both cases. Is there a simpler way to write both cases without just writing double the code?

Comment: If you really want to eliminate the duplication, you could devise a macro—but I don't think it would be simpler.  Even the [`std::iter::Sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Sum.html) trait is implemented with manually separate [owned](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/traits/accum.rs.html#39-48) and [borrowed](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/traits/accum.rs.html#61-70) cases.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of `Sum`. I was just playing around to practice Rust. Thank you for letting me know they cover both cases. Then I think I understood this completely :)